# Correct order of functions in JS file

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out if im using the correct order for my functions and then calling the load and resize event in the correct place/order. Here is an example of my Javascript file:

```
function init() {
// code
  imgLoad.on('done', function(instance) {
    initContent();
  });
}

function initContent() {

  calcStyles();
  initIntro();
  initProjects();
  initFooter();

}

function calcStyles() {
// code
}

function initIntro() {
// code
}

function initProjects() {
// code
}

function initFooter() {
// code
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  init();
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(init, delay);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Of the functions in your code, any order will work, for two reasons:

- Function declarations are hoisted - `function foo() {` in a given scope will automatically have the function put into the `foo` identifier before any real work gets done (such as assigning to non-function-declaration variables, or adding event listeners)
- Even were it not for hoisting, any order would still work, because the two possible starting points:

  ```
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  ```

  will only start running their callbacks *after* all of the JavaScript on the top level of this script file has finished running - so, all of the functions will be defined by the time one of them first gets referenced by one of the listeners.